# Appending zeroth element to a list, then iterating while appending the rest

Tags: python

```
a = [] 
a.append(0.99)
for i in range(5):
    a[i+1] = a[i] * ((1+((d*c)/2))/(1-((d*c)/2)))
    a.append(a[i+1])
```

`IndexError: list index out of range` coming from the fourth line.

I've tried a hand full of different methods, but can't seem to get it right. The output should look something like:

`[0.99, ####, ####, ####, ####]`

I'm sure it's something real simple, and I believe the error involves the 0th element of the list, any chance of help?

Should spit out the same answers as:

```
 a0 = 0.99
 a1 = a0 * ((1+((d*c)/2))/(1-((d*c)/2)))
 a2 = a1 * ((1+((d*c)/2))/(1-((d*c)/2)))
 a3 = a2 * ((1+((d*c)/2))/(1-((d*c)/2)))
 a4 = a3 * ((1+((d*c)/2))/(1-((d*c)/2)))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a.append(a[-1] ** ((1+((d*c)/2))/(1-((d*c)/2))))
```

Comment: I added more after your comment. When testing your answer the values didn't come out the same.

Comment: I take that back, Moe I typed my code in wrong, and squared instead of multiplying. This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a list in python you can't access indices that don't have values yet (even if you want to assign them) unless you use `.append()`, and that is why you are getting index error. A work around for that is to have `None` values of the size you want or `0` values, for example:

```
a = [0] * 5
a.append(0.99)
for i in range(4):
    a[i+1] = a[i] ** ((1+((d*c)/2))/(1-((d*c)/2)))
    # no need to append now
```

now `a` will be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and you can access by indices normally.

EDIT:

I noticed in your recent edit that you want to multiply `a` by `((1+((d*c)/2))/(1-((d*c)/2)))` but you are using `**` in the code example which means **to the power of**. You should use `*` instead.

Comment: Okay, I was under the impression that simply setting the length of the list would allow me to access the indices, guess not. Upvote for that and catching my error, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped!